# NSDictionary release triggers valueForKey return value release

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am currently trying to work myself into iOS development. Right now I'm having trouble understanding memory management.
This is the cause of my confusion:

```
NSString *path = [self.dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dummy.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *dummyKeyValue = [dict valueForKey:@"dummyKey"];

// NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithString:dummyKeyValue]);

[dict release];

NSString *anotherString = [dummyKeyValue lowercaseString];
```

This piece of code triggers an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the last line. Seemingly because NSDictionary releases its key values. What I don't understand is why the `dummyKeyValue` definition is not being taken into account, because obviously `dummyKeyValue` is still pointing to the value of `"dummyKey"`.

Now the next problem and even funnier phenomenon occurs when you comment out the `NSLog` line. Using `dummyKeyValue` in one way or another seems to prevent the release of the memory it points to. WHY?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In manual reference counting mode, simply defining a variable doesn't mean that the object the variable points to will automatically be kept around. When `dict` is released, it releases its value objects, and if there are no other objects with a strong reference to them (i.e. their reference count is now 0), they are released. That's what you appear to be seeing here.

If you want to keep a strong reference to dummyKeyValue, you need to retain it after receiving it. Of course, that also means you need to release it when you're done with it. Try this:

```
NSString *dummyKeyValue = [[[dict valueForKey:@"dummyKey"] retain] autorelease];
```

Now dummyKeyValue will stick around until the end of the current autorelease pool scope. Often, accessor methods are written to do just this before returning a value to avoid exactly the situation you're seeing.

Worth noting is that if you were using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting), you wouldn't have this problem as the compiler would insert the necessary retain/release calls to ensure that dummyKeyValue stuck around until you were done with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is basic memory management. When you create `dict`, the dictionary is managing the memory of all of the keys and values it contains.

When you get a value and assign it to your `dummyKeyValue` variable, you are not doing any extra memory management on the value. You simply have a variable pointing to an object.

Now when you release `dict`, the dictionary also releases all of its keys and values. In other words, all of the keys and values have their retain count reduced by one. Since, at this point, nothing else has retained the keys and values, they are all deallocated.

At this point, your `dummyKeyValue` variable it pointing to a deallocated value which is causing the crash.

You have to options to fix this.

1. Retain the value stored in `dummyKeyValue` (which will need to be released).
2. Move the call to `[dict release]` to after your last use of `dummyKeyValue`.

The reason the `NSLog` statement appears to fix the problem is because your `NSLog` creates an autoreleased `NSString`. This `NSString` retains the value you used to create it. So when  `dict` is released, the `NSString` still has a reference to the same object as `dummyKeyValue`. This allows that object to live a little longer preventing the crash.

Answer (score 2):

(You should be using `objectForKey:` to retrieve things from an `NSDictionary`.)

First, turn on ARC. If you're just starting with Cocoa, there's plenty of other things about the environment that you need to learn besides memory management. The vendor-bundled compiler will take care of 99% of your memory management issues, and you should let it. This has always been a major stumbling block for new Cocoa developers, and it's now been obviated. Come back to this topic later, once you have a grasp on everything else. Now, ignore the remainder of this answer. There is no step three.

That said, this is what's happening here:

When you get an object out of the dictionary using `objectForKey:`, you don't get ownership of it. It's just a reference, and the dictionary still owns the object. If you destroy the dictionary, all of its objects go with it -- unless they're also owned (retained) by something else. If you want the object to live past the destruction of the dictionary, you need to make a claim on it with `retain`:

```
NSString *dummyKeyValue = [[dict objectForKey:@"dummyKey"] retain];
```

Having taken ownership like this, you're now also responsible to relinquish that ownership, either by using `release` when you are done with the object, or by autoreleasing it, in which case it will be released sometime after the end of this method.

Using the retrieved object as the argument to `stringWithString:` makes it live on because, apparently, as an internal detail you can't rely on, that method is retaining and autoreleasing the argument. Or something else you can't rely on. It's an interesting find, but not a practical method of managing object lifetimes.

Comment: "turn on ARC. Then ignore the rest of this answer." is the worst advice one could give to someone trying to understand memory management.

Comment: @H2CO3: I know you hate ARC, but it really is the way forward for Cocoa development. That's meant to be slightly tongue-in-cheek anyways: you're right that it's important, at some point, to understand reference counting even if it's automatic.

Comment: It's not that I hate ARC (I do, but that's another question), it's that one should definitely know how refcounting works, regardless of the technology/actual implementation used.

Comment: I think there's plenty of other stuff that can be learned first. ARC works, and it removes possibly _the_ number one stumbling block for new Cocoa devs. Ref counting definitely needs to be learned at some point, but someone just starting with iOS doesn't need to know immediately that classes are objects, that `@"My string"` creates a compile-time constant, that ivars used to have to be declared in `@interface`, and neither do they need to know, _right away_, that you used to have to send `retain` and `release` everywhere. I don't think either of us will convince the other on this, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
NSString *dummyKeyValue = [[dict valueForKey:@"dummyKey"] retain];
```

or

```
NSString *dummyKeyValue = [[dict valueForKey:@"dummyKey"] copy];
```

It does not matter that you have a reference to an objec, since you are not useing ARC. Each object has a reference count. Your `dummyKeyValue`'s ref count is 1 until your dictionary exists. When you release it, the ref count decreases (becomes 0) and the object is deallocated. So the `dummyKeyValue` points to nothing.

BTW, if you want to increase teh ref count of an object, use `retain`, and `release` for decreasing it.

Comment: You stated "When you release it, the ref count decreases (becomes 0) and the object is deallocated. So the dummyKeyValue points to nothing." The last part is not true. When the object is deallocated, the `dummyKeyValue` still points to the same location. At this point it could be garbage memory or even another object. It doesn't point to "nothing" until you set the variable's value to `nil`.

Comment: That is what I meant by "nothing". Maybe not the best expression for deallocated instance :).